# Start React Native command line interface

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, react-native

this is the first time I started to work on the **React Native Android Application** But I am facing problem while opening React Native command line interface and I don't know how to open it please any one help me regarding this or provide me a link from where I can able to make a demo app.

Comment: Please provide more info..Explain what you've tried and what went wrong. Simply saying "I have a problem" doesn't help us identify the problem.

Comment: This is the first time with react native app  I Used this link to get some thing through it so that I can start on Initial level
[link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/getting-started.html)
But I don't know how to open React Native command line interface.

Answer (score 10):

install node.js and then run:

```
npm install react-native-cli -g
```

This installs react-native-cli globally so you can open command line and run

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

Comment: Yeah this is a problem with the wording of the React Native Getting Started docs, where it says, "Use the React Native command line interface to generate a new React Native project called "AwesomeProject":

react-native init AwesomeProject" ... it makes it sound like there is some other Command Line Interface you're supposed to "use" somehow, not just type that command into the Windows command prompt. Sigh. React-Native REALLY needs better orientation documentation for new folks, (or if it exists, I don't know where to find it).